# relation between $W_2(\mu,\nu)$ and $W_2(\mu,\nu^*)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be to probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that second moment matrix of $\nu$, is $S_\nu:=\int yy^Td\nu(y)=I_n$. So we define the following measure on the unit sphere  $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ as
$$d\nu^*(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{r^2}{n}d\nu(xr)\qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$$
by this definition of $\nu^*$ i get a probability measure on the unit sphere and its second moment matrix  $S_{\nu^*}=\frac{1}{n}I_n$ because
 $$S_\nu:=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} xx^Td\nu^*(x)=\frac{1}{n}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}xx^T\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{r^2}{n}d\nu(xr)=\frac{1}{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}yy^Td\nu(y)=\frac{1}{n}I_n$$

so can we find any relation between $W_2(\mu,\nu)$ and  $W_2(\mu,\nu^*)$? Where $W_2(.,.)$ is the 2-Wasserstein metric means
$$W_2^2(\mu,\nu)=\inf_{\pi\in\Gamma(\mu,\nu)}\int\Vert x-y\Vert^2d\pi(x,y)$$
where $\Gamma(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of coupling between $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Can someone please recommend any sources that are related to my question.

Comment: What is $S_\nu$? What is the second moment matrix of $S_\nu$ ? What is the formal meaning of $d\nu^*(x)=\frac{r}{n}d\nu(xr)$ ? I'm quite familiar with optimal transport, but I've never encountered these notations.

Comment: I rectify some errors i hope now is more comprehensible. $\nu^*$ is a way to transport the whole mass of $\nu$ to a single point of unit sphere and to have a specific second moment matrix.